# Como configurar o Context para não colocar nome da tabela no plural?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estou numa aplicação ASP.net MVC 5, configurando uma classe `DbContext`.

Quando o EF gera o banco de dados, as tabelas referentes aos objetos da aplicação estão ficando com os nomes no plural. Por exemplo:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Teste.Models.Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }      
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Teste.Models.Imagem> Imagem { get; set; }
```

No banco, as tabelas ficam assim:

```
dbo.Categorias.
dbo.Imagems.
```

Como configurar para não colocar no plural?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adicione na sua implementação de `DbContext` esse método:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();   
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Outra alternativa seria "forçar" o nome da tabela:

Ou usando a annotation `Table`

```
[Table("Categoria")]
public class Categoria 
{

}
```

Ou no método `OnModelCreating`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Categoria>().ToTable("Categoria");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```